# SUM() agrupando resultados de soma por linha

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

Salve, salve! É a minha primeira vez aqui no Stack Overflow, então se o assunto for repetido, desde já peço desculpas.

Estou com um problema ao utilizar o SUM(). A questão é: quando chamado a função fora do CASE WHEN que estou montando, ela soma normalmente os valores das linhas de terminada coluna.

```
SELECT SUM(quantidade_faturada) FROM SFT_GRADE_PEDIDO WHERE NUMERO_PEDIDO = '280';
```

O resultado:

| QUANTIDADE |
| --- |
| 1218 |

Porém, ao colocar em um CASE WHEN, tenho o seguinte resultado:

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN gp.quantidade_faturada = '0' THEN SUM(gp.quantidade_produzida)
            WHEN gp.quantidade_faturada > '0' THEN SUM(gp.quantidade_faturada)
            END AS QUANTIDADE
FROM SFT_GRADE_PEDIDO gp 
WHERE NUMERO_PEDIDO = '280'
GROUP BY gp.quantidade_produzida, gp.quantidade_faturada;
```

| QUANTIDADE |
| --- |
| 252 |
| 276 |
| 450 |
| 240 |

Verificando a tabela SFT_GRADE_PEDIDO, notei que o agrupamento se dá pelos dados existentes na coluna QUANTIDADE_CAIXAS, que possui 4 valores diferentes.

[image: Tabela SFT_GRADE_PEDIDO]

De que forma seria possível somar toda a coluna de quantidade (faturada ou produzida, a depender do caso) ao invés de agrupar os resultados, dentro de um CASE WHEN?

Answer (score -1):

A síntaxe que foi tentada não funciona , uma solução é fazer um SUM no CASE.

```
SELECT sum(CASE 
            WHEN gp.quantidade_faturada = '0' THEN (gp.quantidade_produzida)
            WHEN gp.quantidade_faturada > '0' THEN (gp.quantidade_faturada)
            ELSE 0 
            END) AS QUANTIDADE
FROM SFT_GRADE_PEDIDO gp 
WHERE NUMERO_PEDIDO = '280';
```

Fontes

[Case](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

[Group By](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html)

Comment: Obrigado, Motta! Deu certo!

Porém, uma dúvida de caráter técnico, de quem tem pouco experiência em SQL: esse agrupamento se deve a clausula group by que é exigida do SUM() dentro do case when?

Comment: Neste caso não tinha GROUP BY pois este já é o total geral.